# Java Intellij IDE importing builtin classes cannot be resolved

Tags: java

```
import javafx.scene.Scene;             //cannot resolve (Scene is red)
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane; //cannot resolve (AnchorPane is red)
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;       //cannot resolve (Pane red)
import javafx.stage.Stage;             //cannot resolve (Stage red)

import java.io.IOException;            //cannot resolve (IOException red)
import java.io.*;                      //can resolve    (all good)
```

the pattern is that whenever I import anything, for example, java.io.I, then the suggestion,"IOException" comes up, but when I use it, it becomes red and says cannot be resolved.

Further, something like:
    System.out.println;
the println part would also be highlighted in red

However, if I say,    import someBuiltinClass.*; , that always works.
My question is how can I fix this problem? (JDK is defined as Java9.0)

Comment: did you set up the project jdk?

Comment: @Coder-Man yes I did

Comment: @VinceEmigh I think it will work if whenever I need to import, I import by  java.io.*; , but it shouldn't be a problem if I import by the class name.